# Replace string from last without changing string length

Tags: javascript

Suppose I want to generate a string base on some incremental no and a specified string.

```
const originalStr = 'activator'
const str1= '100';
const str2= '4659';
const str3 = '12345';
const str4 = '123456789'
```

Now want to replace the originalStr from last without changing its size like

```
//for str1 my expected output is 'activa100'
//for str2 my expected output is 'activ4569'
//for str3 my expected output is 'acti12345'
//for str4 my expected output is '123456789'
```

How I do this using JS?

I tried the following method:
Is their any better method than this? How to ensure result size always 9

```
const originalStr = 'activator'

const str1= '100';
const str2= '4659';
const str3 = '12345';
const str4 = '123456789'
const str5 = 'sizeWillChanged'

console.log(str1.padStart(9,originalStr)); //'activa100'
console.log(str2.padStart(9,originalStr)); //'activ4659'
console.log(str3.padStart(9,originalStr)); //'acti12345'
console.log(str4.padStart(9,originalStr)); //'123456789'
console.log(str5.padStart(9,originalStr)); //'sizeWillChanged'
```

Comment: Please add the code you've tried

Comment: `.padStart` ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `slice()` to remove `n` characters from `originalStr` from the end. So that the new characters can be prefixed to `originalStr` without affecting the original length of `originalStr`.

```js
const originalStr = 'activator'
const str1= '100';
const str2= '4659';
const str3 = '12345';
const str4 = '123456789'

function replacing(str, token) {
  return (str.slice(0, -token.length) + token);
}

console.log(replacing(originalStr, str1));
console.log(replacing(originalStr, str2));
console.log(replacing(originalStr, str3));
console.log(replacing(originalStr, str4));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const originalStr = 'activator'
const str1= '100';
const str2= '4659';
const str3 = '12345';
const str4 = '123456789'

function replaceFromEnd(string1, string2){
    return string1.substr(0, string1.length - string2.length) + string2;
}

console.log(replaceFromEnd(originalStr, str1));
console.log(replaceFromEnd(originalStr, str2));
console.log(replaceFromEnd(originalStr, str3));
console.log(replaceFromEnd(originalStr, str4));
```